# Network problems with Windows VM in Bluemix

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

This weekend (11/8) I started to experience problems with the network in my Windows VM. The internet connection is simply gone.

Does anyone else experiencing the same problem? How to fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

yes I confirmed that VMs are having connectivity issues on both US and UK regions. VM team is working to solve it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

the issues with VMs has been solved today and the notification in the status page has been taken down

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status